# Resources for Computer Vision Algorithms and Applications

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, reference-request

Are there any videos or other books/notes/slides that anyone has come across that follow Computer Vision Algorithms and Applications by Richard Szeliski? We are using this book in class but the professor did a bad job explaining and I have some trouble getting through the book. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "that follow Computer Vision Algorithms and Applications by Richard Szeliski"

Comment: Notes or slides that follow along with the book.